# How to get box around contour using skimage.segmentation.felzenszwalb?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm trying to get a box around a segmented object on the edge of the image, that is, there is no contour around the segmentation because the object is only partially inside the image region.

I use `skimage.segmentation`, `find_boundaries`, `clear_border`, and `regioprops`. However, `regionprops` does not provide those edge cases

```
segments_fz = felzenszwalb(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), scale=300, sigma=0.5, min_size=50)
cleared = clear_border(segments_fz)
label_image = label(cleared)
regionprops(label_image)
```

A box around segmented object near the limit of the image region.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `clear_border`. Then the objects on the border will be treated like any other. The `bbox` property should give you a bounding box for your object of interest, while [`find_boundaries`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.find_boundaries) and [`mark_boundaries`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.mark_boundaries) will let you get or visualise the boundaries between segments.